# Is every pair of NP-Complete problems reduced in polynomial time?

Tags: np-complete

[image]

As shown above, several NP-Complete problems are derived from GSAT (general satisfiability problem) by a polynomial-time reduction.

Then, my question is that is every pair of NP-Complete problems reduced in polynomial time? In other words, I think that the above graph should be represented as a complete graph by the definition of NP-Hard. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Let $A,B$ be two NP-complete problems. Then, by definition,

1. $A,B\in NP$
2. Every language $L\in NP$ can be reduced to them.

Hence, since $B\in NP$, then $B\le_p A$, and with a similar argument, $A\le_p B$.

The graph you included shows the **only** the reductions we used to prove NP-completeness of the problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!